# Две кнопки на сайте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Все доброе время суток 
Возник такой вопрос -  на сайте есть кнопка

`<button id="btn-drw-pp" class="btn-drw-pp"></button>`

при нажатии на которую всплывает **pop-up** окно реестрации онлайн визита

Сам `JS` код находится на другом сервере и немогу изменить, вызов функции происходит по `ID`

Как разместить даную кнопку на сайте в двух местах, хочу в меню и в блоке сайта, что они работали.

```html
<script>
    window.drwInitPP = function() {
        drw.initPP({
            id:   "58d3756483870f0089f0041b77138a3b47b4ddb1b0ba7b00abde7ba95f144f852b499cb606d4a581",
            host: "https://drw.pl"
        });
    };
    (function(d, s, id){
        const fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        const js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://drw.pl/static/plugins/drw-pp.min.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, "script", "drw-pp-init"));
</script>

<button id="btn-drw-pp" class="btn-drw-pp"></button>
<button id="btn-drw-pp" class="btn-drw-pp"></button>
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: и как может работать если у вас два ID  btn-drw-pp ?

Comment: подпишись не на id  а на класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так можно...)))

```js
$(".btn-drw-pp").on('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let $currentElement = $(event.currentTarget);
  let $idButtonElement = $('#btn-drw-pp');
  if (!$currentElement.is($idButtonElement)) {
    $idButtonElement.triggerHandler('click');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-drw-pp" class="btn-drw-pp">1</button>
<button id="btn-drw-pp" class="btn-drw-pp">2</button>
```

Но вы должны понимать , что два DOM-элемента с одинаковым ID на странице является не валидным кодом. Так что у второй кнопки лучше вместо атрибута id использовать атрибут data-id="btn-drw-pp" и повесить на него обработчик клика, при котором триггерить событие клика элемента с ID.